# In HBase, when max version parameter set, what does it do exactly?

Tags: hbase, hbasetestingutility

I'm working on a mock HTable in memory. I compared my HTable with a mini-cluster's HTable. Mini-cluster is something used for HBase application test, I use it here to get some standard result. In mini-cluster, there's a

`HBaseTestingUtility.createTable(byte[] tableName, byte[] family, int numVersions)`

api. when the numVersions set,

`HTable.get(Get)`

will return at most numVersions versions of result, even if the maxVersion parameter in Get is set bigger than numVersions. And if the parameter isn't set, the default value is 1. But in some other test, I find that in fact, there's many versions saved when numVersions is 1. So I want to know what happen when the numVersions is set exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'numVersions' sets the amount of rows that remain, at maximum, after major compaction. In other words, more versions of a row may be saved, but those are scheduled for cleanup. Those rows are still there, but may not be read as that would create unreliable behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never used compaction related APIs, so one more question: is it mean that if some compaction operation involved, the versions outside of 'numVersions' are cleaned up, and if not, versions outside can get inside when those new versions are deleted?

Comment: That is a good question for which I dont have an answer as of yet. Can you ask it as a separate question? Then let me know I might dig in the hbase code to find out. I suspect before compaction versions can get outside and back inside if later other versions are deleted, but to be sure would require deep knowledge I dont posses or digging for which I might make time.

Comment: By the way, there is no need to use a compaction api. It is something hbase does automatically periodically. Its good to read about it a bit.